# Contain p text within div horizontally

Tags: html, css

I made a friends list script for a website and noticed some funny looking UI issue in the chat section. When a chat message thats very long gets added to the chat content div which has the attribute `overflow: scroll`, it stretches it out horizontally, like this:

[image: chatDiv]

I need to make it so the `<p>` tags within the content div wrap to the next line if they're wider than the content div so this doesn't happen. My css right now looks like this:

```
#chatContentDiv {
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 75, 0.3);
    text-align: left;
}

#chatContentDiv p {
    font-size: medium;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I need it to still be scrollable up and down but can't have it extend sideways if the message contains a very long word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

Use  `word-wrap` property to break the word, if it is wider than the wrapper

```
#chatContentDiv p {
    font-size: medium;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
```